# Apple Shortcut - query state of bedtime

Tags: shortcut, alarm

I want to set up a shortcut, which sets airplane mode ON when I charge my phone while it's at scheduled bedtime.

The best would be to set up automation *When Charger Is Connected* test *if bedtime is ON* then *set airplane mode ON*.

But when I set the automation in my iOS, the *if* script is very limited, it allows me only pass input

- Select a Home Accessory
- Clipboard
- Current Date

I thought I could set up a shortcut that will test bedtime for me and I would run this Shortcut via the Automation, but again, I cannot find a way how to query for bedtime status.

Is there any way how to access the current state of bedtime? Will the Pythonista script help?

Comment: Any particular reason why airplane mode rather than do not disturb? DND would allow the phone to complete its backup.

Comment: feng-shui  , I just want completely turn off the radio when I put my phone on the charger near my bed

Comment: I just used formatted date and two ifs to test the current time whether it is in the same timespan as my scheduled bedtime, it was not easy and is hard to maintain, but hey, it works. Querying the state of bedtime from the system would be much easier and smarter.